# Trying to avoid a for loop with numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I am searching a way to access an array of data, with an array of array that contains the interesting index, and without making a for-loop. The array of array is dtype=object, because each individual array are of different sizes.
I build a simple exemple:

```
myArrayData = np.random.rand(100) ### a classical np.array
myArrayOfIndex = np.array( [ np.array([1,2,3],dtype=np.int32),
                             np.array([4,5,6,7],dtype=np.int32) ] )
### the array of array containing the index
### it is automatically a dtype=object because of the sizes of the sub-array
```

I can not access my data with this 'object array':

```
myArrayData[ myArrayOfIndex ]
```

The myArrayOfIndex can contain all size of array, even [ ].
Of course I can do a loop over myArrayOfIndex, but it not really efficient.

Is there a way to make it without a loop?

Or should I think to organize my data/indexing in an other efficient way (the one use here is simple and intuitive... but not working)!?

I am editing my question because it is perhaps too 'general':

Practically I have several myArrayData: myArrayData1, ..., myArrayDataN each one contain a different 'physical' property of all my 'particles'. myArrayOfIndex contain sub-arrays, each of them contains indexes of 'particles' that link to the data, but they do not have necessarily the same number 'particles'.

For the moment I do a loop over myArrayOfIndex and extract data:

```
np.array( [ myArrayData[i] for i in myArrayOfIndex ] )
```

But as some can notice, make a loop over a np.array can be considered as a sin! ( :) ) So I am interested to know if there is a way to avoid this for-loop. It is at the same to optimize my code, than to learn python.

Comment: Your indexing operation is not defined if your index array is going to be staggered. What do want to happen?

Comment: I work with an array of np.array because all the sub-arrays have different sizes, I can not build a multidimensional array!  Like myArrayOfIndex in the question has two sub-array of sizes '3' and '4' !

Comment: Yes, I edited my comment. I don't understand what output you want from `myArrayData[ myArrayOfIndex ]` since this isn't defined.

Comment: I would like myArrayData[ myArrayOfIndex ] to returns an array of array that contains the data of the indexes:
in the example it should be np.array( np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6,7]) )

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : is there a way to define myArrayData[ myArrayOfIndex ] ? Or do you have an idea how to transform myArrayOfIndex in a way to myArrayData[ myArrayOfIndex ] be possible ? knowing the constrain on myArrayOfIndex.

Comment: to be clear, the solution is easy with a loop :

    np.array( [ myArrayData[i] for i in myArrayOfIndex ] )

but I would like to know if there is a way to avoid this loop, 
a 'Pythonic' way :) that give the same result.

- I look at 'map', but I did not manage to make it
- I also try to find if a 'nullIndex', index that return nothing, but I find nothing...

Comment: isn't the resulting array just a simple copy of `myArrayOfIndex`? without the dtype information

Comment: ok in the example yes, but this is just because myArrayData = np.arange(100), it can be random(100), then it is different!!

Comment: There are a time and place for loops in Python, and this seems like one to me. You maybe could combine all the index arrays together, use it as the index, then split the result back into smaller arrays, but that may be really convoluted and possibly slower.

Comment: No magical numpy trick :( I will have to live with it. Thank for the comments. Should I close the question?